# Log changes made to LINQ to SQL generated objects

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, logging

I was wonder what would be the best way to log changes made to objects created by linq.

I have searched around and this is what i came up with:

```
using (testDBDataContext db = new testDBDataContext())
{
    Sometable table = db.Sometables.Single(x => x.id == 1);

    table.Something = txtTextboxToChangeValue.Text;

    Sometable tableBeforeChanges = db.Sometables.GetOriginalEntityState(table);

    foreach (System.Data.Linq.ModifiedMemberInfo item in db.Sometables.GetModifiedMembers(table))
    {
        // Obviously writing to debug is not what i would like to do
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Old value: " + item.OriginalValue.ToString());
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("New value: " + item.CurrentValue.ToString());
    }
}
```

Is this really the way to go to log changes?

Comment: What kind of LINQ? LINQ to XML?

Comment: then, in future, you should _say so_

Comment: @JohnSaunders ok im sorry, im quite new in here so im trying to learn

Comment: ok, then learn that there are many different things named "LINQ to something", so you need to specify which one you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive searched around and i think im gonna use DoodleAudit (doddleaudit.codeplex.com) it seems to give me what i wanted, tnx for helping anyways!

Answer (score 0):

[Change Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280462.aspx) or [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489.aspx) are the way to go. LINQ has nothing to do with it. As a general rule, client side cannot properly track changes that occur in the server because the changes may occur in alternate access that is not occurring through the client. As a cautionary note, setting up a complete data audit for all changes is seldom successful as the performance tax penalty is usually too high.

Comment: @RemusRusanu Wow...that feels quite super complex for a beginner as myself...any way to make this a easier way?

Comment: You need to clarify what you want to log and why. Explicitly state the the requirements you have.

Comment: Well the object is a Customer object, with lots of customer info like phone, email, www. In my company all employees can log in and see/edit the data of the customer. Now i would like to log what changes employees does so i could show for example the last 10 changes made like: "Customer name changed from A to B 2011-06-20"

Comment: Can the data change through any other mean beside your app? Eg. import jobs, maintenance jobs, manual updates, some other application sharing the data?

Comment: No only the website that our employees use

Comment: One option is to have a version history of the entities of interest. Eg. CustomerHistory keeps a version for each customer, as it changes. This solution has the advantage of being very easy to reconstruct the state of the customer in the past (at previous versions) but it consumes space. The other option is to have a table of changes and to log the changes field-by-field on the object of interest. This has the advantage of being more space savy, but reconstructing an entity previous version is non-trivial.

Comment: Ive searched around and i think im gonna use DoodleAudit (http://doddleaudit.codeplex.com/) it seems to give me what i wanted, tnx for helping anyways!